# Universal background-color code for Blogger

Tags: html, css, blogger

I'm doing some tests on a new theme and it has a dark mode, but some texts have a white background (my shit when making posts). Is there any code that makes the background of all texts transparent? Because it's a lot post.

[code](http://www.filedropper.com/code)

[background color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcOKm.jpg)

Comment: We need to see your code. Add a [mcve] to your question please

Comment: Ok, sorry. Uploud the code.

Comment: No, not links or images of code. Actual code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using CSS to do this. Probably all your text is in some type of element with some class, like for example:

```
<div class="text-container">
```

If this is the case, then use CSS to target those elements, something like:

```
.text-container p{ 
    background: none;
}
```

Maybe a good idea is to add a class to your main "container" element when dark mode is active (use [JS toggle()](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp) for example) and then using CSS you can change all the styles of your text only when this class is in the HTML (so basically when dark mode is on).

Take a look at [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) to know more about CSS selectors. Play around with your CSS code and I'm sure you will manage to solve this!

Answer (score 0):

As the commenter said, a code example would be a great help. However, as a general solution, this should work fine:

```html
<style>
p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
   background-color: transparent;
}
</style>
```

If it doesn't work fine, either:

1. There is an inline style overriding it
2. It is something other than the tags listed above

We'll need more context (ie, a code example) to assist further

Answer (score 0):

Please, can you add some lines of your code in your question? Just to see if there's something inside your css code that's messing around your text.

Be careful making `<span>` tags inside p, h1, h2... and then adding an css style onto it. For instance:

```css
h1 {
  width:250px;
  color:purple;
}
h1>span {
  background-color:white;
}

body {
  background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1><span>White background text here</span></h1>
  <h1>Normal "transparent" text here</h1>
</body>
```